# Object type is same as type in inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I want to return from my Connection class only Account object and that works great.

```
public class Connection : Account
{
    public Account GetAccountData ()
    {
        Account acc = (Account) MemberwiseClone(); 
        return acc;
    }
}
```

But acc.GetType() returns "Connection".
What am i doing wrong? I need to have acc.GetType() to be equal to "Account". #EDITED# Okay, here is a piece of code in which need to get only Account object from Connection.

```
Connection ClientConnection = 
FindConnectionViaIdentifier(connection.RemoteUniqueIdentifier);
if (ClientConnection != null)
{
Account account = ClientConnection.GetAccountData();
Debug.Log(account.GetType().ToString());
// Serializing
 om.Write(PacketSerialization.SerializeToByteArray<Account>(account));
}`
```

So im trying to serialize Account object wich i got from Connection class, but i can't serialize it, because it's type is not Account but Connection. Here's serializtion code:

```
static class PacketSerialization
{
    public static byte[] SerializeToByteArray<T>(this T obj) where T : class
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this byte[] byteArray) where T : class
    {
        if (byteArray == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            var obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(memStream);
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

## EDIT this is how account class looks

```
[Serializable, DataContract(Namespace = "Alveria Data")]
public class Account
{
    [DataMember] public string AccountName { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string Token { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public List<Character> CharacterList { get; set; }

    public Account(string accountName, string token, List<Character> characterList)
    {
        this.AccountName = accountName;
        this.Token = token;
        this.CharacterList = characterList;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you using GetType() for? Some context might help with a more comprehensive solution.

Comment: You are calling `MemberwiseClone()` from an object that _is_ a `Connection` object. Why would expect that to clone anything other than the `Connection` object? And given that it's cloning the `Connection` object, why would `GetType()` return anything other than `Connection`? Your question makes zero sense.

Comment: It's server side code. I need to send in bytes only Account object to client, but i can't serialize like this "SerializeToByteArray<Account>(acc)", because it's type is Connection. It's type cant be Connection, cause client would not deserialize it.

Comment: Are you the owner of the Account and Connection classes? IE, you can edit these classes.

Comment: If you want to serialize your object as `Account`, ask a question about _that_. Just because you store the result of the clone in a variable having type `Account`, that doesn't strip all the extra features of the `Connection` object and make the object into an `Account`. The variable only governs what your code can use in the object, not what the object actually _is_.

Comment: When did a Connection become a type of Account?  I can imagine one possibly containing the other, but they are both unrelated to each other.

Comment: @jwdonahue Account became Connection

Comment: Does an Account quack like a Connection?

Comment: @jwdonahue Account is just bunch of variables

Comment: Right, so your connection should _contain_ an Account object, not try to be one.

Comment: Birds fly, most ducks fly, so do crows, therefore Ducks and Crows inherit from Bird.  Never use inheritance when composition will suffice. Bird doesn't inherit from Crap, despite the fact they are all full of it.

Comment: @jwdonahue Yeah, you are right, i didn't think about that. Thank you so much! :D